# Create Array from Object - ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can I create an Array from an Object just in one line? I don't want all the values object, just a selection:

```js
const myObject = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c:'yep' }

const { a, c } = myObject
const myArray = Array.of(a, c)

console.log(myArray)
```

Could I use destructuring in some way inside the `Array.of` parameter?

Comment: Why dont you want to use `Object.keys` & `Array.map` methods?

Comment: I only asked myself how to keep it as simple as possible :)

Comment: If your point is to codegolf the solution, then: `myArray=(({a,c})=>[a,c])(myObject)`

Comment: Just write your solution in one line. A bit shorter: `const { a, c } = myObject, myArray = [a, c]`. Even an imaginary solution cannot be shorter, so maybe you explain your objective.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just :

```
const myObject = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c:'yep' };
let arr = Array.of(myObject.a, myObject.c);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yep, that could be a reasonable solution but I just wanted to avoid repeat references to the Object or to the keys